# Is there any way to add borders to a table generated by to_latex()?

Tags: pandas, latex, pylatex

I am creating a table by passing `DataFrame` to `to_latex()`, which is generating a table without a border. Is there any way to add it?

Comment: Seems not. I just `df.to_latex(...).replace('{lllllllllllllll}', '...', 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re # Use regular expression to search for column declaration section of LaTeX table
tex_content = df.to_latex(index=True, escape=False) #Or whatever options you want/need
print(tex_content)
re_borders = re.compile(r"begin\{tabular\}\{([^\}]+)\}")
borders = re_borders.findall(tex_content)[0]
borders = '|'.join(list(borders))
tex_content = re_borders.sub("begin{tabular}{" + borders + "}", tex_content)
print(tex_content)
# Or save tex_content to a ".tex" file
```

Answer (score -2):

Refer this, https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables

```latex
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 

 \hline

 cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\ 

 cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\ 

 cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\ 

 \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the original poster is asking for a programmatic way to do that.

Comment: yup. exactly. Please let me know if there is any programmatic way to add border. I have large number of tables which are getting printed using to_latex(). Can't add border manually for all these tables(as size vary for each table).